# How to move image without using ACTION_MOVE?

Tags: java, android, image, move, ontouchlistener

When I open my app on the left top corner appears image, when I touch it image starts to move towards bottom right corner. Now when I stop moving my finger (while touching image) image stops as well, how to make image move without interruption?

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int X = (int) event.getX();
        int Y = (int) event.getY();
        int action = event.getAction();

        imgX += 1;
        imgY += 1;

        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (X >= 0 && X <= img.getWidth() && Y >= 0 && Y <= img.getHeight()) {
                    img.setX(imgX);
                    img.setY(imgY);
                }
                else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    finish();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: move your code from action move to action down case

Comment: I've tried to do that, but then when I touch image code is executed just once, so image moves a bit and then it stops.

Comment: In that case you can use a Boolean variable. Until that variable is true keep moving that image and in up event make that variable false